# Why do i get a different results from my weekly code vs per week code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why am I getting different results when I compare weekly results into using a code individually per week. Does it have something to do with the timestamp?

This is the code for all the weeks:

```
select date_trunc('week',date_joined) as week, COUNT(*) as count from auth_user 
where date_joined>='01-01-2019' and date_joined<='31-03-2019'
group by week
order by week
```

This is the resulting table:
[first result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW43K.jpg)

This is the code for getting an individual week:

```
select COUNT(*) from auth_user where date_joined>='31-12-2018' and date_joined<='06-01-2019'
```

This is the result for the first week: [second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoZFl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that `date_joined` is a timestamp, and your second query misses the entries from January 6th.

Try with

```
AND date_joined < '2019-01-07'
```

Also, you should use ISO notation: YYYY-MM-DD